# What is the difference between: 1. browser.wait(EC...) 2. browser.wait (function () {}) 3. browser.sleep()

Tags: jasmine, protractor, automated-tests

Explaine me, please, what is the difference between those three variants of code? They all are working well.

Or maybe the first and second variant are identical? 
What about the third one: I read that "browser.sleep()" is better to avoid in code, as it cause unstabilities in tests work. Is it true?

Help me to understand.

Thanks.

```
var MenuSigninButton = $('button.btn');
var LoginDropdownForm = element(by.id('loginForm'));

MenuSigninButton.click();
    browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(LoginDropdownForm));
```

and

```
MenuSigninButton.click();
    browser.wait (function () {
        return LoginDropdownForm.isDisplayed()
    });
```

and

```
MenuSigninButton.click();
browser.sleep(3000);
    expect(LoginDropdownForm.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
```

Comment: Don't you need to pass timeout to `wait()` as second argument?

Comment: Hello again :) I thought the timeout is 30 seconds by default. But yes, in examples it is usually set..

Comment: Yep. Thanks :) I didn't even know about default timeout. Actually first two are the same. However, EcpectedConditions contain a lot of [other useful conditions](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions) which can be simply used instead of creating complex custom functions. So IMO it's better (more convenient) to use EC... As for `sleep`: it's really bad practice and you should avoid using hardcoded sleeps as your test runs will take extra time that you can save with `wait`

Comment: Great! EC variant looks more minimalistic and understandable for me ;) So, if there's no big difference, i will prefer to use it futher.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, yes, **you should avoid use driver.sleep() as long as you can**. Why?

Well, if you started to use that is because you are waiting something to appear on the screen in order to continue the execution of the test. 
Well, you don't know how much time it will last that "something" to appear.

- Maybe sometimes the time that you hardcoded is too short, and the test will fail, giving a fake result.
- Maybe, the time is too long, and the test will last too much, and you could save that time.
- Sometimes, the two points above could happen depending on time, overall load of the env,...

**Second question:**

When you use *browser.wait()*, you have to pass a condition to stop the wait. 
It can be a *Promise* that will be solved on the future(not covered on your examples), it can be a condition(First example) or it can be a function, that has to be executed (Second example).

The **third example** is a bit different:

When you use the *expect* method, you are explicitly writing a condition that must pass in order to pass the test. For that reason, expect does not ends until the Promise inside it is resolved.

Comment: Ok, with "expect" I understand. But, for example, what kind of "browser.wait" will you use in my cases?